# Иконки не цветные

Tags: android

Использую эти исходники https://github.com/TechCybo/Android-App-From-Responsive-Website-NavDrawer

В меню(activity_main_drawer) все картинки поменял, они цветные
Скомпилировал, получилось это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в android studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Скрины ссылками на неизвестные сайты? Нет, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй использовать app:itemIconTint в NavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:itemIconTint="#f00"
app:itemTextColor="#0f0"
app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer" />
```